# How to set ivy shared repo root with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I want to have a single shared ivy repository and several local repositories(one per-user).
How can I configure sbt to set a path to shared ivy repository ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by edit the $HOME/.sbtconfig

add the following JAVA_OPTS

-Dsbt.ivy.home=/shared/.ivy2/

Note: $HOME/.sbtconfig was setup when I installed SBT via MACPORTS. You can also add the JAVA_OPTS directly to the SBT script.

The information above is explained here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#ivy-home-directory